# Python list sorting dependant on if items are in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Say I have a list:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

and a second list:

```
B = [3,6,9]
```

What is the best way to sort list A so that anything that matches an item in list B will appear at the beginning so that the result would be:

```
[3,6,9,1,2,4,5,7,8,0]
```

Comment: Is B necessarily sorted?

Comment: No, A and B can be in any order to begin with. They don't necessarily need to be sorted at the end as long as the ones in B come before the ones in A.

Comment: @Ashy what do you mean they don't *necessarily* need to be sorted, do you want them sorted in the end?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are in original order or sorted as long as the ones that appear in B are first, again in no specific order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> B = [3,6,9]
>>> sorted(A,key=lambda e: e not in B)
[3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

How this works:

`sorted` sorts an interable based on the result of `key(element)` for each element (the default value for `key` is `None` which results in it sorting based on the elements directly).

In our case the lambda `lambda e: e not in B` will return either `True` if `e` ***isn't*** in `B`, or `False` if `e` ***is*** in `B`. The element's with `False`'s get sorted to the front, and you end up with your result. As demonstrated by:

```
>>> sorted([True,False,False])
[False, False, True]
```

Comment: update to the question: `A` can be in any order, so this currently does not work

Comment: @jamylak: but the OP also said that the exact output order doesn't matter, and the example the OP gave -- `[3,6,9,1,2,4,5,7,8,0]` -- preserves the original order instead of being sorted.  So I think this solution works (although if the sizes were larger it might make sense to turn B into a set).

Comment: nice, but prefer `e not in B` to the equivalent `not e in B`

Comment: @wim you're right, that's much more Pythonic! Sometimes I forget about such niceties.

Answer (score 3):

Many of these answers are using set logic explicitly. But Python has it built in. If, as you say, the order doesn't matter as long as the `B` parts come first, this will take care of the rest:

```
B = set(B)
list(B.intersection(A)) + list(set(A) - B)
```

This assumes that (as in your example) there are no duplicate values. If there are, use one of the list comprehension answers.

Comment: +1 But I would do `>>> A, B = set(A), set(B)`
`>>> list(A & B) + list(A - B)` That should be faster too because  `B` doesn't need to get implicitly converted to a `set` twice like it does in this case. Also `A` is converted to a `set` twice

Comment: @jamylak He may want to reassign the whole thing to `A[:]`, so I took your advice, but skipped the permanent `set`ting of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> B = [3,6,9]
>>> [i for i in B if i in A] + [i for i in A if i not in B]
[3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>>> B = [3,6,9]
>>> b = set(B)
>>> sorted(A, key=b.__contains__, reverse=True)
[3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this will remove duplicate values - but works given unique keys.**

If both are already sorted (or otherwise ordered as you wish), then you can use:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
B = [3, 6, 9]

from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

print list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain(B, A)))
# [3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

Otherwise, just apply `sorted` to `A`, `B` or both...

Comment: what if an item in `B` is not in `A` I don't think we should add it to the list